# BeanDefinitionParsingException in executable jar file

Tags: java, spring, executable-jar

I have following code:

```
//preparing DAO objects
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("test-context.xml");
surveyDao = (SurveyDao)context.getBean("surveyDao");
recordDao = (RecordDao)context.getBean("recordDao");    
//creating GUI
createWindow();
```

The problem is that it runs perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it to executable jar it crashes with following

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException
>   unable to locate Spring NameSpaceHandler for XML schema namespace
>   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
>   Offending resource: file test-context.xml

test-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config/>

<!--     <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="org.openforis.collect.context.ApplicationContextAwareImpl" /> -->

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:${user.dir}/dev.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${collect.devdb.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${collect.devdb.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${collect.devdb.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="surveyDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.SurveyDao" init-method="init">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.LogoDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="recordDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.RecordDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="taxonomyDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.TaxonomyDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="taxonDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.TaxonDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dynamicTableDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.DynamicTableDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTest" class="com.arbonaut.collcomm.main.MyTest" init-method="init" />



    <!--  Managers -->
    <bean id="recordManager"                    class="org.openforis.collect.manager.RecordManager" init-method="init" />   
    <bean id="surveyManager"                    class="org.openforis.collect.manager.SurveyManager" init-method="init" />

    <!-- Expression Factory -->
    <bean id="expressionFactory" class="org.openforis.idm.model.expression.ExpressionFactory" />
    <bean id="validator"                    class="org.openforis.idm.metamodel.validation.Validator" />
    <bean id="externalCodeListProvider"     class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.DatabaseExternalCodeListProvider" />

    <bean id="taxonVernacularNameDao" class="org.openforis.collect.persistence.TaxonVernacularNameDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- enables interpretation of the @Transactional annotations for declarative transaction management-->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the spring-tx jar on the classpath / rebundled into your executable jar?

spring-tx-3.1.0-RELEASE.jar contains the xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd:

`/org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd`